# Is it possible to use @truffle/contract in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, truffle

[Here is the package I would like to use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/contract)

How can I import this in a TypeScript file (without using require)

What is the proper syntax?

None of these work:

```
import contract from "@truffle/contract";
import Contract from "@truffle/contract";
import TruffleContract from "@truffle/contract";

import { contract } from "@truffle/contract";
import { Contract } from "@truffle/contract";
import { TruffleContract } from "@truffle/contract";

import * as contract from "@truffle/contract";
import * as Contract from "@truffle/contract";
import * as TruffleContract from "@truffle/contract";
import * as alias from "@truffle/contract";
```

Comment: did you fix this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try this way:

```
const truffle = require("@truffle/contract");
const res = await fetch('/contract.json'); //contract.json - is your compiled contract
const artifact = await res.json();
const contract = truffle(artifact); //here will be TruffleContract object
```

...

Comment: But OP asked **without using require**

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that. For me it was a problem to make it working in typescript :)